# How to get more than 1000 search results with API Github

Tags: angular, github-api

I want to list the most star Github repo that were created in the last 30 days,  but to display more than 1000 search, I have this error message

{
  "message": "Only the first 1000 search results are available",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"
}

**do you have a solution for this problem?**

**thank you in advance**

Answer (score 2):

[zifan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8504091/zifan-yan) is right.
You can create a query per day for the last 30 days; or two queries per day (one each 12 hours); and so forth. The lower the interval, the more the query calls. At the same time, the more the repositories you catch.

Below an example in Python. It runs a `curl` call, so you can easily translate it to different languages.

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

URL = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=is:public created:{}..{}'
HEADERS = {'Authorization': 'token <PASTE_HERE_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>'}

since = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)  # Since 30 days ago
until = since + timedelta(days=1)   # Until 29 days ago 

while until < datetime.today():
    day_url = URL.format(since.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), until.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    r = requests.get(day_url, headers=HEADERS)
    print(f'Repositories created between {since} and {until}: {r.json().get("total_count")}')

    # Update dates for the next search
    since = until
    until = since + timedelta(days=1)
```

Of course, the number of repositories might still be too large. In that case, try

1. to use pagination;
2. to reduce the interval SINCE..UNTIL, as well as the timedelta;
3. to add further filters in the query, for example: exclude archived and forked repositories, get repositories with a minimum number of stars only, and so forth.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-repositories-collector/blob/master/repocollector/github.py#L9) for an example.
Here is a Python tool to collect repositories from Github: https://github.com/radon-h2020/radon-repositories-collector

Comment: I tried running your snippet but it returns None for each day.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. Indeed, the api endpoint was wrong (search/repository instead of search/repositories). I edited the script and tested it.

Comment: @SarveshBhatnagar The code works as of writing. Perhaps you had a problem because you were unauthenticated?

Answer (score 0):

as per git hub API v3 documentation, the GitHub Search API provides up to 1,000 results for each search.
https://developer.github.com/v3/search/

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue. I think the only way work around is to split your query into small query which returns less than 1k result. (refer to [github search limit results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602893/github-search-limit-results))