# How to get N commits for a repository that match a certain string with github api?

Tags: github, github-api

The [example on the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-commits) shows that to find commits that match a string, `+` can be used as in:

`q=repo:octocat/Spoon-Knife+css`

if one would like to look for commits that include `css` in the `Spoon-Knife` repo for `octocat`. I wonder if there's a way I can get N numbers of commits (for example, get only 10, or get 10,000)

I see there are two parameters I might be able to use, but only to get up to 100:

```
per_page    integer     query          Results per page (max 100).

page        integer     query          Page number of the results to fetch.
```

Not really sure how to use `per_page` to get way more commits than 100.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/traversing-with-pagination

Comment: @BertrandMartel what I understand after reading this is that I should query the same url, with per_page=100 (which is max) as many times as I need to reach my desired number. e.g. Loop over 20 times to get 2000 items. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct, you increment the page param and set per_page to 100

Comment: but the search api is limited to 1000 results max see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602893/github-search-limit-results)

Comment: default is most recent first I think, do you have an example ?

Comment: The link header for v3 api. See the first link