# How to see all results using GitHub search bar

Tags: github

When I [search](https://github.com/search?q=rust), I see that GitHub is reporting 244,685 repos. But there are only 10 repos per page and 100 pages, making 1,000 total viewable results. Is there any way to see all of the results other than using the API?

Comment: Use the pagination: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28

Comment: is there an equivalent way to do this using only the browser as stated in the question?

Comment: What are you actually tying to achieve here? Are you going to click through all the pages? (Also note 10 * 100 is 1,000, not 100,000, and that's the limit of the search API - https://stackoverflow.com/q/37602893/3001761.)